# How to make add to cart button on custom page (not shop/product page) Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

i made new page on my site that people choose PC part to buy..

My case is how to create a button for add all product choosen to cart then redirect to the cart pages.

[image]

Select list HTML Code

```
<div><select id="ddrakit-processor" class="ddrakit"><option value='{"gaming":"0","render":"0","priceperform":"0"}'>- Pilih processor -</option><option value='{"product_id":9,"category_id":17,"harga":"100000000","gaming":"20","render":"10","priceperform":"20"}'>Intel i99 - Rp. 100,000,000,-</option></select></div>
<div><select id="ddrakit-motheboard" class="ddrakit"><option value='{"gaming":"0","render":"0","priceperform":"0"}'>- Pilih motherboard -</option><option value='{"product_id":11,"category_id":20,"harga":"80000","gaming":"40","render":"50","priceperform":"10"}'>ASUS ROG Z999 - Rp. 80,000,-</option></select></div>
<div><select id="ddrakit-ram" class="ddrakit"><option value='{"gaming":"0","render":"0","priceperform":"0"}'>- Pilih memory RAM -</option><option value='{"product_id":10,"category_id":19,"harga":"500000","gaming":"40","render":"10","priceperform":"20"}'>V-GEN 128GB DDR8 - Rp. 500,000,-</option></select></div>
<div><select id="ddrakit-vga" class="ddrakit"><option value='{"gaming":"0","render":"0","priceperform":"0"}'>- Pilih graphic card -</option><option value='{"product_id":8,"category_id":16,"harga":"2000000","gaming":"10","render":"20","priceperform":"10"}'>RADEON RX 999 - Rp. 2,000,000,-</option><option value='{"product_id":16,"category_id":16,"harga":"16499000","gaming":"20","render":"10","priceperform":"20"}'>MSI - GeForce GTX 1080 Ti Gaming X Trio - Rp. 16,499,000,-</option></select></div>
<div><select id="ddrakit-psu" class="ddrakit"><option value='{"gaming":"0","render":"0","priceperform":"0"}'>- Pilih power supply -</option><option value='{"product_id":17,"category_id":22,"harga":"50000","gaming":"10","render":"50","priceperform":"10"}'>Corsair RM8000 8000w - Rp. 50,000,-</option></select></div>
<div><select id="ddrakit-casing" class="ddrakit"><option value='{"gaming":"0","render":"0","priceperform":"0"}'>- Pilih Casing -</option><option value='{"product_id":12,"category_id":21,"harga":"5020000","gaming":"10","render":"10","priceperform":"10"}'>Corsair Casing Gaming - Rp. 5,020,000,-</option></select></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I dont know how your page to be redirected looks like and what values it expectes, but you can get your selected values or texts easily with `jQuery`. 

`$.each($('select').find('option:selected'),function(e,v){//values are in v});`

Answer (score 0):

Use this link in your custom page

`<a href="?add-to-cart=<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>`

Comment: My page contain multiple product, how to add them all into a single button?

Comment: You can use the given lines of code within the loop of products. then it will work differently for each product by their product id.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying a form? I'd use a backend server to handle the form and do the redirect to the checkout page and whatnot. Submitting form is what you should use and it's straightforward to implement.

Comment: How to do that? what should i write or reference

Comment: Feel free to come back to me if you still having difficulty in implementing one.

Comment: Why use form? can you explain it?

So, is unable to just create a single button to add all product at once?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

you may paste this where you want to show add to cart button

```
<?php
global $product;
$pid = $product->get_id();
?>
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart_url id=' . $pid . ']' ) ?>" class="your-classes-here">Add to cart</a>
```